# bootstrap navigation bar not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My bootstrap navigation bar is not working in mobile platform. If i open my website my navigation bar extends until it block my website contents. This is my website [live demo](http://www.iconis.com.my). Moreover, my website navigation bar color is black but once i open in mobile it becomes gray color. Even my content is not resizing actually. I tried to use the bootstrap grid.

Heres the html code for the bootstrap grid:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
                    <ul class="sigs">
                        <li class="col-md-6 col-lg-2">
                            <button id="myPopOver" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" title="Leader: Lim Teik Han" data-content="Scope & Objective: Appreciate the theory, 
                            principle and application of internationally adopted business process improvement body of knowledge framework such as SCOR(Supply Chain Operation Reference),
                             CPFR(Collaborative Planning, Forecast, and Replenishment), BSC(Balanced Scorecard), Lean Six Sigma, TOC(Theory of Constraints), BABOK(Business Analysis Body of Knowledge).">Business Process</button>
                        </li>

                        <li class="col-md-6 col-lg-2">
                            <button id="myPopOver1" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" title="Leader: Shamsul Anuar Abdul Wahid" data-content="Scope & Objective: Disseminate contemporary Enterprise Architecture(EA)
                             body of knowledge, such as TOGAF(The Open Group Architecture Framework), FEA(Federal Enterprise Architecture), ZIFA(Zachman Information Framework Architecture).">Architecture</button>
                        </li>

                        <li class="col-md-6 col-lg-2">
                            <button id="myPopOver2" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" title="Leader: Wong Chow Jeng" data-content="Scope & Objective: Reinforce all kind of advanced ICT applied research that exhibits
                             high intent to go for commercialization and formulate strategies to monetizing research works.">Academics</button>
                        </li>

                        <li class="col-md-6 col-lg-2">
                            <button id="myPopOver3" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" title="Leader: Kitt Lee" data-content="Scope & Objective: All contemporary programming languages, UML(Unified Modelling Language), UX(User Experience) and the-state-of-the-art software architectures.">Programming</button>
                        </li>

                        <li class="col-md-6 col-lg-2">
                            <button id="myPopOver4" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" title="Leader: -TBA-" data-content="Scope & Objective: All kind of entertainment-oriented game development and competition.It includes film studio production.">Game & Simulation</button>
                        </li>

                        <li class="col-md-6 col-lg-2">
                            <button id="myPopOver5" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left" title="Leader: -TBA-" data-content="Scope & Objective: ">Social Media & Online Marketing</button>
                        </li>

                        <li class="col-md-6 col-lg-2">
                            <button id="myPopOver6" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" title="Leader: Dr Lim Lian Tze" data-content="Scope & Objective: ">Data Science & Analytics</button>
                        </li>

                        <li class="col-md-6 col-lg-2">
                            <button id="myPopOver7" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" title="Leader: Chen Woon Wee" data-content="Scope & Objective: ">Business Development</button>
                        </li>

                        <li class="col-md-6 col-lg-2">
                            <button id="myPopOver8" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" title="Leader: -TBA-" data-content="Scope & Objective: ">Mobile App</button>
                        </li>

                        <li class="col-md-6 col-lg-2">
                            <button id="myPopOver9" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left" title="Leader: -TBA-" data-content="Scope & Objective: Disseminate contemporary technologies to develop and deploy Cloud Computing solutions.">Cloud Computing</button>
                        </li>

                        <li class="col-md-6 col-lg-2">
                            <button id="myPopOver10" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" title="Leader: Chuah Pei Kern" data-content="Scope & Objective: Propel a comprehensive undestanding of equipment interface and embedded technology using Arduino as a demonstration toolset.">Arduino</button>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
<div class="container-fluid">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="col-xs-3 col-md-4">AGI-Goldratt Institute<br></li>
                            <li class="col-xs-3 col-md-4">Agile Institute <br></li>
                            <li class="col-xs-3 col-md-4">Chartered Institute of IT <br></li>
                            <li class="col-xs-3 col-md-4">FEAC Institute <br></li>
                            <li class="col-xs-3 col-md-4">MESA International <br></li>
                            <li class="col-xs-3 col-md-4">Institute of Business Forecasting and Planning <br></li>
                            <li class="col-xs-3 col-md-4">International Association for Contract and Commercial Management <br></li>
                            <li class="col-xs-3 col-md-4">International Institute of Business Analysis <br></li>
                            <li class="col-xs-3 col-md-4">Institute of Business Process Management <br></li>
                            <li class="col-xs-3 col-md-4">Supply Chain Council <br></li>
                            <li class="col-xs-3 col-md-4">The Open Group <br></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

Comment: The color of your sidebar is not black, that's why you see the gray. Change the css property at _style.css, on line 739_. As for your second problem, could you specify which all content is not being re-sized correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can collpase your nav-bar for small sizes and have a drop down menu instead.This helps in presenting your content on mobiles.

Bootstrap has few built in classes which will help you to achieve this.
Have a button inside the header class.

```
 <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
```

The above HTML will collapse the menu to a toggle button for mobiles.

Have another div with id

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">....
 <!-- Menu items for mobile -->
</div>
```

You can find the documentation here -[Link](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)

Comment: ram but this is a plugin called slidebar so he didnt use the navbar-collapse class. I guess you can see the live demo through your mobile www.iconis.com.my

Comment: @user3663313 Ya i saw it just now.But Why use another plugin?any pirticular reason?

Comment: ram yes because the slidebar plugin looks nice and as per request by my client actually. So i dont have choice on the navigation bar

Comment: @user3663313 went through sidebars website(http://plugins.adchsm.me/slidebars/).it is used for sidebar not for navigation.

Comment: owh now i get it. thanks for the info btw... i have solved it

Answer (score 1):

```
http://www.iconis.com.my/js/jquery-ui/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.1.custom.min.js 404 (Not Found)
http://www.iconis.com.my/js/jquery-qtip-1.0.0-rc3140944/jquery.qtip-1.0.js 404 (Not Found) 
http://www.iconis.com.my/js/lib/jshashtable-2.1.js 404 (Not Found)
http://www.iconis.com.my/js/frontierCalendar/jquery-frontier-cal-1.3.2.min.js 404 (Not Found)
http://www.iconis.com.my/css/frontierCalendar/jquery-frontier-cal-1.3.2.css 404 (Not Found) 
http://www.iconis.com.my/css/jquery-ui/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.1.custom.css 404 (Not Found)
http://www.iconis.com.my/img/coming_soon_ribbon.png 404 (Not Found)
```

Check you have those files properly uploaded to your host, my browser is returning those errors.

Comment: actually i am not using those js anymore ready. the image i forget to upload it. but the website should work fine without those files actually